# What is the degree of a vertex in the complete graph $K_n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and let $K_n$ denote the complete graph on $n$ vertices. Compute $\deg(v)$ if $v \in V(K_n)$.

So I know that $K_n$ is a simple graph with n vertices that have one edge connecting each pair of distinct vertices. I also know that $\deg(v)$ is supposed to equal the number of edges that are connected on $v$, and if an edge is a loop, its counted twice. This is where I am stuck because I cannot imagine how the graph of all positive integers would look like so I don't know how many edges are connected to each vertex.

I know that the total degree of any graph $G$ is twice the number of edges so would the answer be $2n$ but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: I also need help, since I cannot see anything else than a "Let $n\in$"

Comment: This is a very easy problem. Could you explain us what you have tried? what are the definition that you have? For instance you should start by thinking "what is the definition of complete graph?"

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues So I know that Kn is a simple graph with n vertices that have one edge connecting each pair of distinct vertices. I also know that deg(v) is supposed to equal the number of edges that are connected on v, and if an edge is a loop, its counted twice. This is where I am stuck because I cannot imagine how the graph of all positive integers would look like so I don't know how many edges are connected to each vertice.

I know that the total degree of any graph G is 2 times the number of edges so would the answer be 2(n) but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Firstly I’m sorry your first question here has been so thoroughly downvoted. Thanks for editing your question and providing some info. Ok, now to math. The total degree is the sum of all the deg(v), so that’s not relevant here. The number of edges is also not 2n. Remember that every edge is made by two points, so how many ways are there to choose 2 points out of n points? Now to your question. deg(v) is the number of edges coming out of a given point. Because every two points are connected in a connected graph, each individual point is connected with every other point in the group of n.

Comment: @D.R. Thank you for your response. I am afraid I still don't understand. A little slow in math. So the number of edges would be N choose 2? is that right. I am confused.

Comment: I've made an answer

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I’m sorry your first question here has been so thoroughly downvoted. Thanks for editing your question and providing some info. Ok, now to math. The total degree is the sum of all the deg(v), so that’s not relevant here because the question is only asking for one deg(v). The number of edges is also not 2n. Remember that every edge is made by two points, so how many ways are there to choose 2 points out of n points?

- your answer of n choose two: $\binom n 2$ is correct.

Now to your actual question. deg(v) is the number of edges coming out of a given point. Because every two points are connected in a **complete graph**, each individual point is connected with every other point in the group of n points. There is a connection between every two points.

[image]

For example, look at the $K_7$ graph's top vertex. It's connected to all 6 other points (6 lines coming out of it), and hence it's degree is 6. This is the case for every one of the vertices of the $K_7$ graph, and so $\deg(v), v \in V(K_7)$ is just 6. Can you figure out what $\deg(v), v \in V(K_n)$ is?

Comment: deg(v),v∈V(Kn) would be n - 1 ?

Comment: that's correct. Yay!

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: Of course! If you're satisfied with the answer, you can accept it, and if you want more clarification or extension you can comment. I hope your first experience here wasn't too bad, and welcome to MSE!